# Rails: storing variables in a class instance without a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to test out several landing page versions. Each version will have several variables such as:

```
@headline = "The Best App Ever"
@description = "Here's what the app does"
@hero_image = "hero.jpg"
@theme = "dark"
```

Ideally I would like to set only one variable in the controller, like:

```
@version = 1
```

And then in my view, I could call:

```
@version.hero_image
```

I'm sure this is really simple but I've never had to do it without actually creating a model and storing in the DB. Where should I store all these properties of each "version"?

Answer (score 1):

You could define these as a series of hashes or json objects in an initializer that is referenced by a constant.

```
/initializers/homepage_versions.rb

HOMEPAGE_VERSIONS = [{:headline => xxxx, :description => xxxx}, {:headline => xxx}...etc]
```

Then in your controller just do something like @version = HOMEPAGE_VERSIONS[0]